# Stored strings, Locale resource files, using C# 6 Interpolation?

Tags: c#, .net, string-interpolation, c#-6.0

With the existing `String.Format`, I could throw the format string in a database or resource file, instead of having it hard coded into my application.  Is that possible with Interpolation?

I'm guessing not, as it seems to be a compiler checked thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it's a compiler thing as this:

```
string result = $"{name}";
```

Is compiled into this:

```
string result = string.Format("{0}", name);
```

And you can't run the compiler on these stored strings.

You can store the strings with the numbered parameters though, and use `string.Format` explicitly.